# MySQL high CPU usage slows down the server, how to optimize my query?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, sql-optimization

I have a problem when I'm reading data from MySQL database in every second with multiple clients MySQL CPU usage raises to 26-27% and after that my other service which measures and logs real time data into database slows down/crashes.

So I run two different web applications in same server:

Application 1 is a webpage that is cyclically inserting data into database in every second. When only this service is running MySQL CPU usage is approximately 1,8-2,0% and Memory usage is about 275 MB and all is running smoothly and data is logged database as it should in every second. So I think that logging part is not the problem.

Application 2 is also a webpage which reads data cyclically from the database and shows it to user(render graphs from data) and it also does it in every second(so this service shows live data to user which is stored in database by Application 1). When opening the page JavaScript calls php-page with xmlhttprequests and php-page fetch data from MySQL database. When I have 6 different graphs in my page(updated in every second so one client is executing 6 queries(xmlhttprequest to php-page) in every second) MySQL CPU usage raises to 11,0-12,0% and memory usage stays about the same. So now I have both of my applications running and all still goes as it should: Other application stores data in MySQL every second and other application fetches data in every second and shows it to client.

However when another client appears (for example opening application 2 with browser on mobile or just opening application 2 in two tabs with same browser window) MySQL CPU usage raises to 24,0-26,0% memory usage stays about the same as before and my application 1 is not working properly anymore.. It still stores data in every second that's not the problem, but data which I want to store is live measurement data and this measurement part is timed out because of high CPU usage, so values that is now stored are not correct ones(last measured value is stored again and again).

So what I want to achieve is to lower CPU usage caused by MySQL queries from application 2 so that my application 1 still works even if there are multiple clients in application 2.

Here is my php-code that is called with xmlhttprequests in every second which fetches data from MySQL:

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword", "mydatabase");

 // Check connection
 if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 $taulu = $_POST["taulu"];
 $jaksominuuttia = $_POST["jaksominuuttia"];
 $muuttujat = json_decode($_POST["muuttujat"]);
 if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 1){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 }else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 2){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 }else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 3){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 }else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 4){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], $muuttujat[3], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC"); 
 }else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 5){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], $muuttujat[3], $muuttujat[4], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 }else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 6){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], $muuttujat[3], $muuttujat[4], $muuttujat[5], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 } else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 7){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], $muuttujat[3], $muuttujat[4], $muuttujat[5], $muuttujat[6], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 } else if(sizeof($muuttujat) == 8){
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $muuttujat[0], $muuttujat[1], $muuttujat[2], $muuttujat[3], $muuttujat[4], $muuttujat[5], $muuttujat[6], $muuttujat[7], time FROM $taulu WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL $jaksominuuttia MINUTE ORDER by time DESC");
 }        

 $json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 echo json_encode($json );

 // Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Is there something in this code that causes MySQL high CPU usage?

Computer that works as a server has Intel i7-6820HQ 2.70GHz CPU and 16,0 GB RAM. Operating system is Windows 10 Pro and I'm using its IIS. My database is MySQL Community Server v.8.0.11 and I'm using InnoDB engine in my tables. PHP version is v7.2.2.

Comment: Do your query results need to be ordered ? If yes, can you delegate the ordering to client-side code?

Comment: Do the datetime ranges overlap between 2 consecutive queries? Can you reduce the interval length in your query to the time elapsed since the previous query plus a small safety margin ?

Comment: I removed the ordering from queries, but this doesn't have any effect to CPU usage. In my app I fetch this data from time interval e.g one minute and store it in array so result is array length of 60. I do this every second so basically 59 items in this array are same than after last query. However when I changed the solution in a way that I only fetch one value from database which is latest value(WHERE time = NOW()) and store it to array (and this is done of course in every second) the CPU usage still stays the same. Because the nature of my app I need to fetch data in every second.

Comment: Do you have any index on `time` field of the table?

Comment: Awesome @skelwa thanks! I added index to my time column in my tables and CPU load dropped significantly now it's just about 2% even if I have multiple tabs open. I read about indices also before I asked my question but I only tried adding index to column which I'm selecting with $muuttujat[0] and not to time column. I'm a MySQL rookie and wasn't sure how indices work but now I have read from MySQL documentation how those actually works. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html here is documentation page about indices in case anyone else have same issues.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Is the high CPU in PHP? or mysqld?

Comment: High CPU was in mysql.exe, but as I wrote earlier, answer by @skelwa solved my problem