# Mysql 5.7 process shows a long time running, high memory swap

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, swap

in some moments I have had to restart the server since the swap memory shows that it is out of space, I have been reviewing the activity using htop which has shown me that in mysql some processes are started and they last for hours consuming resources as if they will remain beginning and never end.

I appreciate if you can help me or give me an idea of ​​what I should do to improve this process.

Currently I have a machine with ubuntu server 18.04 which has mysql 5.7.1, apache 2.4.29 and php7.3 installed.

[image]

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after min 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; for analysis.

Comment: Hello, following the recommendations I got the following, after 7 days: Delayed_insert_threads 0, Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   0, Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost 0, Slow_launch_threads 0, Threads_cached 6, Threads_connected 2, Threads_connected 291, Threads_running 2.

Comment: Threads_connected at 291 indicates connections are not being CLOSED when the user is through with their activities.  Please post the PHP code used to 'connect', request data, through the end of the connection.  Look for CLOSE in this url for example of closing with mysqli.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513822/mysql-high-cpu-usage-slows-down-the-server-how-to-optimize-my-query  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: Hello, $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mybd"); ........ mysqli_close($link);. However, before executing the connection, I restart the mysql service, leaving the values: Threads_cached: 1, Threads_connected: 1, Threads_created: 2, Threads_running 1; after executing conection show this Threads_cached 2, Threads_connected: 1, Threads_created: 3, Threads_running: 1.  where Threads_cached increase 2 and Threads_created to 3....After disconnecting, shouldn't it stay the same?

Comment: A) Please post the PHP code used to 'connect', request data, through the end of the connection.  B) Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; for analysis. C) One hour later, Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; for end of an hour thread analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqld is a long running process so 9h is ok. Its threads as shown in htop have a more limited lifespan.

Overall the mysql memory usage looks quite low (the amounts are for the main process, all threads use the main process amount).

While there is some swap space used here it not excessively large. You only run out of swap space after you run out of memory. In the htop output here there is still lots of memory available. The brown is page cache, the OS's disk cache that is unused memory. Swap space usage when there is still ram available is ok, the OS will swap it out if there was a need.

So in short, I can't see any problem here. It all, based on the information provided, looks quite normal and there is no immediate danger of out of memory or CPU.